# How to fix "11" constantly repeating

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to make the code print palindromic numbers in the range (10 to 1000) but it keeps returning 11

```
 public class Problem{

    static int temp=0;

    static int isReverse; 

    public static int revNum(int d, int n){

        for (int i = 0; i<(Math.log10(d)); i++) {
            temp *= 10;
            temp += n%10;
            n = (n - (n%10))/10;

        }
        return temp;
    }   

    public static int checkNum(int n) {
        if(revNum(n,n) == n) {
            isReverse = n;
        }
        return isReverse;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 10; i <1000; i++) {
                 System.out.println(checkNum(i));
             }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of 11, 22, 33, 44 and so on, but the actual output is 11, 11, 11 ... (repeats the right number of times, but only one value).

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: It looks to me like isReverse gets set once (at 11) and then you keep returning that over and over when you call checkNum

Comment: I am not qualified enough to use it yet

Comment: 1) Eliminate both static variables 2) don't use `int` for variables called `isBlah`; 3) @daniu What debugger? You don't need a debugger here. Digging into this thing with a debugger is a waste of time.

Comment: You should use local variables for `temp` and `isReverse` instead of static fields.

Comment: to echo Samuel: don't use static variables that persist across method calls. Just declare them _in_ each method, and return them, so you know they only contain values relevant to that very specific call stack.

Comment: Using your debugger would really help you understand what's happening with each variable.  Stepping through this kind of thing with a debugger, when you don't understand what's going on, is NEVER a waste of time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like others have echoed here, you don't really need the static fields in this case. Local variables will suffice. Also, consider what the `checkNum` method is doing. The reason why you're always seeing 11 being printed is because the integer returned from `checkNum` is 11 until the condition in your if statement, `revNum(n,n) == n`, returns true.

For example, when i = 10, the condition `revNum(10,10) == 10` will return false, and thereby `isReverse` or 0 is returned and printed. When i = 11, the condition `revNum(11,11) == 11` will return true, and thereby `isReverse` is set to 11 and printed out. When i = 12, the condition `revNum(12,12) == 12` will return false. And since `isReverse` will not change in this case, the current value of that variable, 11, is returned and printed out. As the loop goes on, 11 instances of 11 will be printed out because the next time `revNum(n,n) == n` returns true is when n = 22.

What you should do instead is to change the return type of `checkNum` to boolean to detect when this condition returns true. And when it does, only then you should print the number `i` in the loop in your main method so that you can see which numbers in your loop's range are palindromic.

```
// these variables are not really necessary
// int temp = 0;
// int isReverse;

public static int revNum(int d, int n){
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<(Math.log10(d)); i++) {
        temp *= 10;
        temp += n%10;
        n = (n - (n%10))/10;
    }
    return temp;
}   

public static boolean checkNum(int n) {
    return revNum(n,n) == n;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 10; i <1000; i++) {
         if(checkNum(i)) {
             System.out.println(i);
         }
    }
}
```